# How to map some table columns to a Map with the column names as key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have this table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE user_type (
    id TINYINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    ...
    --Some more columns

    can_create BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    can_edit BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    can_delete BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    ...
    --Has 23 more columns that define different permissions

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

And would like to map it to something like this:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_type")
public class UserType{
    @Id
    private Byte id;

    private String name;

    // Some more fields

    //Then this map should contain the remaining 26 permission columns
    //with the column names (can_create, can_edit, etc.) as keys.
    @???
    private Map<String, Boolean> permissions;
}
```

Is it possible to map some columns to a `Map` like that? In all the examples and questions I found they just map two values together, not a column name with its value.

Comment: It's better to bitmask the value in a single column. And write an AttributeConverter to store and fetch as map.

Comment: If the relationship is one-to-one then why do you need such `permissions` mapping?

Comment: @Rono Do you mean storing all permission values in a single column as bits? Wouldn't that make it harder to maintain and query outside of this implementation?

Comment: @Raj If I understand your question correctly, it could be a single class "UserType" with the "permissions" field being a Map, no need for the "UserTypePermissions" class. But the question is still the same, how to map those column names and values to said Map?

Comment: @Ludenife No I mean to say, If it's guaranteed that one `UserType` has exactly one `UserTypePermissions` then you do not need the map at all. Also the design seems wierd, `user_type` has a fk which maps to pk of `user_type_permissions`. IMHO it should be the other way round

Comment: Yes. Actually all if you write an AttributeConverter then it's not hard actually you always doing operation with map. But @Raj's solution is much better if you want to store permission not column wise rather row wise mens one row for one user's one permission one-to-many.

Comment: @Raj But even if the relationship is one-to-one, table "user_type_permissions" has 26 columns. I would prefer not to have each column as an individual field, that's why I'm trying to map them to a Map. Even if I merge both tables into a single one the problem would be the same. About the fk, that is to prevent having user_types without permissions, it could be swapped but I don't think that changes the question.

Comment: @Rono The problem with that approach is that there is a lot of duplicated data (permission names) and no easy way of guaranteeing that all user_types have the same defined permissions.

Comment: @Raj I simplified the code and hopefully made what I'm trying to accomplish more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the following approach.

1. Create an enum that will represent your permission types:

```java
public enum PermissionType
{
   CREATE,
   EDIT,
   DELETE

   // other permissions ...
}
```

2. Create `Permissions` class that will hold the permissions state for a user.

```java
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Permissions implements Serializable
{
   private Map<PermissionType, Boolean> permissions;
   
   public Permissions()
   {
      permissions = new HashMap<>(PermissionType.values().length);
      for (PermissionType permType : PermissionType.values())
      {
         permissions.put(permType, false);
      }
   }
   
   public void setPermission(PermissionType name, Boolean value)
   {
      permissions.put(name, value);
   }
   
   public Map<PermissionType, Boolean> getPermissions()
   {
      return permissions;
   }
   
   @Override
   public int hashCode()
   {
      return permissions.hashCode();
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj)
   {
      if (this == obj) return true;
      if (obj == null) return false;
      if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;

      Permissions other = (Permissions) obj;
      return Objects.equals(other.permissions, permissions);
   }
}
```

3. Create hibernate [custom basic type](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-custom-type) for the `Permissions` in the following way:

```java
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor;
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;

public class PermissionUserType implements UserType
{
   private static final int[] SQL_TYPES;
   
   static {
      SQL_TYPES = new int[PermissionType.values().length];
      for (int ind = 0; ind < SQL_TYPES.length; ind++)
      {
         SQL_TYPES[ind] = Types.BOOLEAN;
      }
   }
   
   @Override
   public int[] sqlTypes()
   {
      return SQL_TYPES;
   }

   @Override
   public Class<?> returnedClass()
   {
      return Permissions.class;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException
   {
       return Objects.equals(x, y);
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException
   {
       return Objects.hashCode(x);
   }

   @Override
   public Permissions nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException
   {
      /*
       * The names are column aliases generated by hibernate, like can_dele5_5_, can_crea3_5_, ...
       **/
      Permissions permissions = new Permissions();
      for (int ind = 0; ind < names.length; ind++)
      {
         Boolean val = rs.getBoolean(names[ind]);
         PermissionType name = PermissionType.values()[ind];
         permissions.setPermission(name, val);
      }
      return permissions;
   }

   @Override
   public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SharedSessionContractImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException
   {
       if (Objects.isNull(value))
       {
          for (int ind = 0; ind < SQL_TYPES.length; ind++)
          {
             st.setNull(index + ind, SQL_TYPES[ind]);
          }
       }
       else
       {
          Permissions permissions = (Permissions) value;
          for (Map.Entry<PermissionType, Boolean> permEntry : permissions.getPermissions().entrySet())
          {
             Integer ind = permEntry.getKey().ordinal();
             st.setObject(index + ind, permEntry.getValue(), SQL_TYPES[ind]);
          }
       }
   }

   @Override
   public Permissions deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException
   {
      if (value == null) return null;
       
      Permissions oldPerms = (Permissions) value;
      Permissions newPerms = new Permissions();
      for (Map.Entry<PermissionType, Boolean> permEntry : oldPerms.getPermissions().entrySet())
      {
         newPerms.setPermission(permEntry.getKey(), permEntry.getValue());
      }
      return newPerms;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isMutable()
   {
       return false;
   }

   @Override
   public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException
   {
       return deepCopy(value);
   }

   @Override
   public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) throws HibernateException
   {
       return deepCopy(cached);
   }

   @Override
   public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException
   {
       return deepCopy(original);
   }
}
```

4. And then use this custom basic type in your entity mapping:

```java
import org.hibernate.annotations.Columns;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_type")
public class UserTypeEntity
{
   @Id
   @Column(name = "id")
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "name")
   private String name;

   @Type(type = "com.me.PermissionUserType")
   @Columns(columns = {
      // the order should be matched with the enum PermissionType
      @Column(name = "can_create"),
      @Column(name = "can_edit"),
      @Column(name = "can_delete")
   })
   private Permissions permissions;
   
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this is what I was looking for. Let me try it.