# Mapping dynamic or "leftover" columns with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, mapping

Considering the following table schema

| id | name | attr1 | attr2 | attr3 | attr4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Is it possible to create an `@Entity` class with Hibernate where a certain subset of columns (`id` and `name` in this instance) are explicitly mapped and everything else is put indiscriminately into a `Map`? Something like the following

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "legacy_crap")
class LegacyObject {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    // ?
    private Map<String, Object> attributes;
}
```

which would enable me to run code like this?

```
final LegacyObject result = // query;

Object columnValue = result.getAttributes().get("attr3");
```

Comment: If you can move those columns inside a json object, yes you can achieve that https://vladmihalcea.com/java-map-json-jpa-hibernate/      BTW, the database should have a  support for json column

Comment: @rorschach Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63981986/6277104) is what you are looking for.